# Fire a hook programmatically

Tags: hooks, wp-insert-post

Is it possible to fire a wordpress hook programmatically? Specifically I'd like to have control of wp-insert-post.

Comment: what do you mean by `I'd like to have control of wp-insert-post.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fire a hook you can use following functions:

1. [`do_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) - executes a hook created by add_action.
2. [`do_action_ref_array`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action_ref_array) - execute functions hooked on a specific action hook, specifying arguments in an array. This function is identical to `do_action`, but the arguments passed to the functions hooked to $tag are supplied using an array.

If you want to apply filters, you can do it by calling [`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) function.